# Krakend added number to request body

Tags: http, encoding, krakend

When I try to use krakend as API gateway and make POST request, it adds an additional number to data.
Example of request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"***","password":"***"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/token
```

Source of request received by webserver(after krakend):

```
b'POST /api/v1/token HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: host.docker.internal:8000\r\nUser-Agent: KrakenD Version 2.4.3\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nX-Forwarded-For: 172.17.0.1\r\nX-Forwarded-Host: 127.0.0.1:8080\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip\r\n\r\n'
b'23\r\n{"username":"***","password":"***"}\r\n'
b'0\r\n\r\n'
```

krakend.json config:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "debug_endpoint": true,
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "endpoint": "/api/v1/token",
      "method": "POST",
      "backend": [
        {
          "url_pattern": "/api/v1/token",
          "method": "POST",
          "host": [ "http://host.docker.internal:8000" ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If I use a direct request to the backend it doesn't contain 23 before the body.

Why do I have this number after the krakend gateway?

Comment: I would do a wild guess and propose that you're observing what is called ["chunked encoding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) in HTTP. If I'm correct, you appear to be somehow dealing with "raw" HTTP while having insufficient knowledge about the protocol–in particular, ignoring the `Transfer-Encoding` field of the server's (gateway's in this case, which is a proxy) response, which, instead, you MUST honor and act accordingly. (And this is not the only aspect you must consider to implement a proper HTTP client.)

Comment: Looks like you're right. Nonetheless I don't understand why krakend changes request and adds custom headers. And how I can avoid this behavior.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot because krakend does not violate the HTTP protocol. Having said that, I'm not familiar with krakend–maybe it has specific configuration knobs to disable such behavior. Note that if the upstream did not tell krakend how long the response's body is, krakend will have to use chunked encoding downstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this option to endpoint helped me resolve this problem:

```
"input_headers": ["Content-Type", "Content-Length"]
```

Detail information:
https://www.krakend.io/docs/endpoints/parameter-forwarding/

PS
My krakend version is v2.4.3(This option called different in previous versions).

Comment: Consider adding [this link](https://www.krakend.io/docs/endpoints/parameter-forwarding/) to your answer, and also mark it accepted (it's OK for SO).